# TStringGrid. Row lines are not drawn when scrolling horizontally

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, stringgrid

In Delphi XE7 FMX platform StringGrid rows are not properly drawn when scrolling the content horizontally.

Steps to replicate:

Place a `TStringGrid` on a form, and add a few column(for example: 10).

At runtime scroll the grid content horizontally, and notice that the row lines are not drawn for the area scrolled into view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the issue in Delphi XE7. The row lines are not painted when you scroll the content horizontally. The same also for the alternating background color if you set that option. These are, however, two different problems. The line drawing has been fixed in Delphi XE8 (no RSP was found) but the alternating color was not fixed before Delphi 10.1 Berlin (see [RSP 14197](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-14197)).

Trying to force a repaint (calling `Repaint()` or `InvalidateRect()`) in Delphi XE7 did not fix the line drawing problem. It seems the only solution is upgrading to Delphi XE8.